# Community not listed to set as default for survey

Tags: community, customer-portal, guest-user, survey, salesforce-survey

I am trying to add a survey to community but there are no communities listed for setting as default for survey. The selection drop down shows 'None'

I am trying on developer org and my community is active and published. I have granted access to Surveys, Survey Invitations and Survey Response objects to Guest user profile for community.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate this issue in my developer org. Here is what I did

**Step 1:** Went to Setup >> Survey Settings >> Enable Surveys and noticed that 'Select the default community for creating public survey invitations' does not have any values

[image]

**Step 2:** Checked list of all available communities from Setup >> All Communities and noticed that they are in Preview state

[image]

**Step 3:** Activated 'E-Bikes' community by clicking Workspaces > Administration

[image]

**Step 4:** Refreshed the survey settings page and observed that 'Select the default community for creating public survey invitations' shows the active community

[image]

Verified this in another developer org where I have enabled surveys already and observed that the list shows only active communities

[image]

[image]

Based on my observation, the only criteria for 'Select the default community for creating public survey invitations' to display results is that the community should be active. If the community is already active and does not show up in the list, I recommend raising a [support case](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&language=en_us). Also, you might want to check if it is a site or community and ensure you are activating the community

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you publish your default Experience cloud site and activate it.

To Publish

1. Go to Builder Click on Publish and wait for some time (you will get an email)

To Activate

1. Go to Builder on the left menu and click on Administrator
2. Go to Setting and Click on Activate Button
   [image]